# Button tag is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I am trying to create a button in React js. I am using WebStorm. When I add the below posted code and run it, I get the below posted errors.

Please let me know how to fix it.

**code**:

```
var React = require('react');

var buttonStyle = {
margin: '10px 10px 10px 0'
};

var Button = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <button
            className="btn btn-default"
            style={buttonStyle}
            onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.label}</button>
    );
}
});
```

**error**:

```
          <button
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this button somewhere else the best practice is to export it as default and then import it where you want to use it.

```
import React from 'react';

var buttonStyle = {
margin: '10px 10px 10px 0'
};

var Button = React.createClass({
  render() {
      return (
          <button
              className="btn btn-default"
              style={buttonStyle}
              onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.label}</button>
      );
  }
});
export default Button;
```

When you want to use it next you import it as a module:

```
import Button from 'pathToComponent/Button'
```

Comment: thanks, would you please answer the following:would you please explain to me what does the sign > in onclick means?and why className="btn btn-default" contains separated string "btn btn-default". (2) what does the sign > in onClick mean. (3)i added the following handleClick: function() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }, but when i clikc the button it does not show the log

Comment: By looking at your questions i would start much softer than React and begin with the basics of HTML and javascript. You mean the arrow at the end of this snippet?
`onClick={this.props.handleClick}>` 
It's the closing tag of `<button hereIsProperties="andTheirValues" >`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which react version are you using.

I tried like this and working for me well.

```
import createReactClass from  'create-react-class';

var Button = createReactClass({
   handleClick: function() {
      console.log("hello world");
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        className="btn btn-default"
        style={buttonStyle}
        onClick={this.handleClick}>{'Button'}</button>
    );
  }
});
```

Working [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9mnvl5y7m)

Comment: i opened the link you specified, and it is working..is sanbox an online reactjs engine? sorry i am completely new to this technology

Comment: another question please, what if i want to add a listener to that button, how can i add it

Comment: would you please explain to me what does the sign > in onclick means?and why         className="btn btn-default" contains separated string "btn btn-default"

Comment: page not found.

Comment: can you please modify it to use the arrow function, is it possible